# How does one calculate the GPU memory required to run a model in TensorFlow?

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow, gpu, deep-learning

Is there a straightforward way to find the GPU memory consumed by, say, an inception-resnet-v2 model that is initialized in tensorflow? This includes the inference and the backprop memories required.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since using `gpu.options.allow_growth` and `gpu_options.per_process_gpu_memory_fraction` for model size estimation is currently a trial-and-error and tedious solution, I suggest using **`tf.RunMetadata()`** in combination with tensorboard.

Example:

```
run_options = tf.RunOptions(trace_level=tf.RunOptions.FULL_TRACE)
run_metadata = tf.RunMetadata()
summary, _ = sess.run(train_step, feed_dict, options=run_options, run_metadata=run_metadata)

train_writer.add_run_metadata(run_metadata, 'step%d' % i)
```

Run your model and tensorboard, navigate to the desired part of your graph and read the node statistics.

Source: https://www.tensorflow.org/get_started/graph_viz

Answer (score 5):

You can explicitly calculate the memory needed to store parameters, but I am afraid it would be difficult to compute the size of all buffers needed for training. Probably, a more clever way would be to make TF do it for you. Set the `gpu_options.allow_growth` config option to True and see how much does it consume. Another option is to try smaller values for `gpu_options.per_process_gpu_memory_fraction` until it fails with out of memory.